# PowerBIClient with a multi-tenant application

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to use Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.PowerBIClient to manage PowerBI workspaces for a number of customers.

I've got code written that works when I'm authenticating using a single-tenant application registered in the same Entra ID tenant as the PowerBI account (using the application ID and a secret generated under that registered application).

Because I plan to use this solution for many customers, I setup a multi-tenant application in my own Entra ID tenant, and then consented and registered that application in the PowerBI tenant.

Switching my code over to use that application ID almost works.  I don't get any errors, but calls to retrieve information using the PowerBIClient just return no results.  It seems like I'm authenticated and authorized, but the results are being filtered by the PowerBI API.

I can query the Graph API without any problem using the multi-tenant application, and I've confirmed that both my original single tenant application and my new multi-tenant application are requesting the same permissions for the PowerBI API (I've confirmed that I get an error when hitting the PowerBI API if querying something I don't have permission for).

Is this just a weird limitation of the PowerBI API?  Has anyone done this before?